# ASP.NET MVC [Authorize] from controller in area can't find Account/Login ActionResult in root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, forms-authentication, user-accounts

I'm trying to setup admin logins for my MVC site. I have an area called Admin with a controller called `ControlPanel`. I've placed the `[Authorize]` attribute above the `ControlPanel` Controller declaration. When I make a call to the index of that controller I get an error saying

> it can't find the Account/Login resource.

The `AccountController` is stored in the root's 'Controllers' folder. The view exists in the root's 'Views' folder.

My `AdminAreaRegistration` class:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { area="Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My `RouteConfig` class:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = "", controller = "Startup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it called ControlPanel?  Or ControlPanelController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route seems to be messed up. Try the code below to configure your routing.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { area="Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Startup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Looks like I was trying to get too creative with my route configs. Thanks!